# Is it ok to ask questions on Stack Overflow to improve my coding skills?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have some questions I want to ask to other (experienced) programmers on Stack Overflow.

The goal of those questions is gaining knowledge to become a better programmer.

I think it's a great idea to ask an experienced programmer I know to take a look at my code. But mostly experienced programmers don't have time for this.

So can I ask such questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It might be helpful to be more specific about what you mean by "gaining knowledge", with an example, i.e.

Comment: Specifically, would you be asking SO to look at code that you think should work but doesn't, or would you be asking (Code Review) to look at code that works just fine, and you'd like to improve it in in other ways.

Comment: I voted to close as "Unclear" because it depends on the details of the questions you ask. If the questions you have in mind aren't more clear than this one, then refer to pi's answer.

Comment: Whatever happened to that mentoring initiative?

Comment: There's a Code Review stack exchange site. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: No, but you can feel free to pm me all your questions.

Comment: If experienced programmers outside of SO don't have time for this, why would you imagine that experienced programmers on SO would?

Comment: I think that this question is not clear.  Post an example of the question you'd ask.  Your question might be on topic, or it might not be.  The reason you post it has relatively little to do with whether the question is on topic or not.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> So can I ask such questions on Stack Overflow?

## No.

This is

1. opinion based
2. not about a specific programming problem
3. too broad

Regarding improvement of working code you may ask at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), instead.

For questions about ["creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour), you can ask them at [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (previously named "Programmers Stack Exchange").

Answer (score 19):

Although you shouldn't just ask on Stack Overflow to have your code looked at, you *can* use Stack Overflow to improve your coding skills. I do it all the time, by *answering* questions (or just by trying to), about things that I don't quite know how to do but would like to. It's a great way to find out about language features, techniques and technologies you didn't know about.

A surprising number of questions (or perhaps it's not at all surprising) can be answered with a bit of googling, persistence and experimentation. And if I get it wrong, a swift handful of downvotes will set me straight. :-)

Comment: Ha, I do the same. I would be more salty about questions which are only one step away from Google but I suppose experience directs your search and helps you put it all together.

Answer (score 18):

Such questions are not strictly disallowed here (I think), they are asked and answered from time to time, *if* they ask about a very specific part of some code. When it's just a huge code dump, asking how to improve it, your question will quickly gather downvotes and close votes.

There is a site specifically created for this, however: [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details on the kind of questions you can ask on Code Review. Below is a summary, taken from that page:

> **I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?**
>
> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer
>   must be "yes" to all questions:
>
> - Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered "yes" to all the above questions, your question is
>   on-topic for Code Review.